# ERROR on fetching data from mysql db using jdbc logstash plugin

Tags: logstash, logstash-jdbc

When I try to fetch data from mysql db using jdbc logstash plugin, I'm facing below error

```
[2019-07-10T07:34:31,806][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline ] Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<TypeError: no implicit conversion of Integer into String>
```

Below is logstash configuration file

```
input{
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/jdbc_driver/mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://<dbname>:3306/<tablename>"
    jdbc_user => "<username>"
    jdbc_password => "<password>"
    statement => "select * from spt_entitlement_snapshot"

  }
}

filter {

   mutate {
        convert => { "account_only" => "integer" }
    }
}


output{

      elasticsearch {
           hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
           index => "agco-entitlements-mysql"
           document_id => "%{id}"
     }

       stdout {
          codec => rubydebug
   }

}
```

It is giving problem with one particular table while working for other tables

Comment: Error is [2019-07-10T07:34:31,806][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ] Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>#<TypeError: no implicit conversion of Integer into String>

Comment: Try to remove the mutate filter and the elasticsearch output and see if anything gets printed to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Have you use the `sql_last_value` with your JDBC plugin?
I had the same issue today and I corrected it with adding `clean_run => true` in the JDBC plugin.

[Here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/error-registering-plugin-pipeline-aborted-due-to-error-typeerror-cant-dup-fixnum-failed-to-execute-action/128987/2) where I found the solution for me.

Hope this will help you.